# jQuery: JS alert fires out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below, if the coded order is followed, should change the div's class, then show an alert; but instead, the alert pops up before the jQuery .addClass() event fires.  How do I make .addClass() fire first?

```js
$('div').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('red');
  alert('.addClass() should fire *before* the alert, but it will only do so after dismissing the alert.');
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.red {background-color:indianred;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `alert` *blocks* the browser - when `alert` is called, further Javascript processing and rendering becomes impossible until the `alert` is dismissed, and the browser hasn't yet had time to repaint the page to reflect the new class.

One possible solution would be to add a small `setTimeout` before the `alert`:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('red');
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me</div>
```

It would be even better to use a proper modal instead of `alert` - `alert` is quite user-unfriendly, after all.

If `setTimeout` doesn't seem elegant enough, you can use `requestAnimationFrame` as well. Passing a function to `requestAnimationFrame` will run the function *synchronously before* the browser repaints, so if you call `setTimeout` inside `requestAnimationFrame`, the timeout callback will run immediately after the browser repaints:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('red');
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('hi');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me</div>
```

Comment: This does work, thank you.  I'm looking into doing it with promises, which seems a more reliable method, and will post a solution if/when I can.  I agree that a modal method would be better, but it also requires a good bit more overhead, and I'm trying to keep it simple for this particular project.

Comment: You can use `requestAnimationFrame` as well if `setTimeout` doesn't seem reliable enough, see edit. Promises are somewhat new, and do not exist for older APIs like `requestAnimationFrame`, so you may as well just use the `requestAnimationFrame` callback, rather than promisify it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, especially regarding promises.  I'll play with `requestAnimationFrame` and see if I like it better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delay and queue`
see example below

```js
$('div').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('red').delay(1).queue(function(){
    alert('.addClass() should fire *before* the alert, but it will only do so after dismissing the alert.');
});

});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.red {background-color:indianred;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me</div>
```

Comment: This basically does what a setTimeout would do, only it unnecessarily hooks into jquery's animation queue. I think using the animation queue for this would be misleading for newer users.

Answer (score -1):

It is not actually show up before the class change, rather it is being rendered so fast before that the browser renders the complete change.

you can try the following

```
$('div').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('red');
   console.log($(this));
   alert('.addClass() should fire *before* the alert, but it will only do so after 
   dismissing the alert.');
 });
```

and you will see in the browser console that the class red is being applied before.